# How do I print the frequency of words in a dictionary

Tags: python

so heres the question (from Grok Learning):

> You're running a poll to find out your friends' favourite dessert and decide to write a program to help you keep track of all the suggestions and who voted for each.
>
> Your program should keep reading in lines (until an empty line) which contain the person's name, then a colon (:) then their favourite dessert.
>
> Your program should work like this, printing out the results in any order:

and they want:

```
Name:vote Harry:treacle tart
Name:vote Hermione:chocolate frogs
Name:vote Hagrid:rock cake
Name:vote Ron:chocolate frogs
Name:vote 
treacle tart 1 vote(s): Harry
rock cake 1 vote(s): Hagrid
chocolate frogs 2 vote(s): Hermione Ron
```

Heres my current code:

```
votes= {}

line = input('Name:vote ')
while line:
  name, vote = line.split(':')
  if vote not in votes:
    votes[vote] = [name]
  else:
    votes[vote].append(name)
  line = input('Name:vote ')


for vote in votes:
  print(vote, 'vote(s):', ' '.join(votes[vote]))
```

which gives:

```
Name:vote Harry:treacle tart
Name:vote Hermione:chocolate frogs
Name:vote Hagrid:rock cake
Name:vote Ron:chocolate frogs
Name:vote 
treacle tart vote(s): Harry
rock cake vote(s): Hagrid
chocolate frogs vote(s): Hermione Ron
```

I don't know how to print the frequency of each names votes

Comment: Just take the length of the list of names; `len(votes[vote])`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add length of `votes[vote]` to your output:

```
for vote in votes:
  print(vote, ' ', len(votes[vote]), ' vote(s):', ' '.join(votes[vote]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print('{} {} vote(s): {}'.format(vote, len(votes[vote]), votes[vote]))
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.